# Google App Engine Bulkloader "Unexpected Thread Death"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I am trying to upload a moderetly sized csv file to google app engine using the bulkloader functionality, and it appears to die some of the way through with the following result:

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20110328.181531
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20110328.181531.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to notmyrealappname.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Starting import; maximum 10 entities per post
...............................................................[INFO    ] Unexpected thread death: WorkerThread-7
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
.........[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-7: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>

[INFO    ] 1740 entites total, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 720 entities (472133 bytes) transferred in 32.3 seconds
[INFO    ] Some entities not successfully transferred
```

It uploads about 700 of the 19k entries I am trying to upload, and I am wondering why it fails. I checked the csv file for errors like additional commas that could throw off the python csv reader and non ascii characters have been stripped out.

Comment: I was able to work around this problem by setting a much higher batch limit (10K) and a greater rps limit (1K)

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is preferred to deleting in situations like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lifting the batch limit (batch_size) and rps limit (rps_limit) works, I use 1000 for the batch size and an rps limit of 500:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url= --application= --filename=  --email= --batch_size=1000 --rps_limit=500
```